# C# How Can I Remove New Added Record Before SaveChanges in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I have a table with an `IDENTITY` key and I need that the user can add a new record or remove an added record before clicking on the Save Button and this button running the **`SaveChanges()`** function and all changes will be saved.

Or how can access to `ID` of the new added record to delete?

**UPDATE:**

My form has a listbox control and two buttons (add & remove)

[image: listBox Form]

Click on add button do open another form that have a list of accessories that bound from database and user can select anyone from list

[image: accessories list]

```
MobileEntities database = new MobileEntities();
tblDeviceAccessory tblDeviceAccess = new tblDeviceAccessory();

tblDeviceAccess.accessory_id = Convert.ToInt16(iHadiTextValues.listAccessoryId); //Selected item id in Accessories list

database.tblDeviceAccessories.Add(tblDeviceAccess);
int accessoryId = tblDeviceAccess.id; //this value is 0 because not run saveChanges() 

listAccessory.Items.Add(new ListItem { Name = iHadiTextValues.listAccessoryName, Value = accessoryId });
```

After selecting the id and text of selected item will add in `listboxcontrol` items and add in database table but **Not Save!**

[image: listbox items]

Then by clicking on the save button, the `SaveChanges()` function will run and all changes will be saved on database.

How can I remove added item to `tblDeviceAccessories` table before `savechanges()` on remove button click?

Comment: Don't just re-post a closed (and deleted) question. Instead, improve it and vote to reopen. Your question isn't clear and you refused to respond to comments on the original question. To me the question seems to be nothing but "how to remove items from a listbox", which has noting to with Entity Framework and saving changes.

Comment: @GertArnold i'm sorry my freind because i am new in stackoverflow, excuse me for my bad question. my mean is that how can delete a new added record in table before save ?

Comment: @GertArnold Please help me to reopen my original question

Comment: Well, just leave it for now. Try to clarify your question.

Comment: You should set the new ListItem.Value to be `tblDeviceAccess`. Then you can grab it from `listAccessory.SelectedValue` and remove it from the dataset

Comment: @Charlieface Thank you. but my problem is id of new added record to delete! because before `savechanges()` value of id is 0 and i cant delete this

Comment: No no. You need to add **the object** to the list, **not** it's id. Then you can remove it from the dataset before you save: `database.tblDeviceAccessories.Remove((tblDeviceAccessory) listAccessory.SelectedValue);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with this code :

```
int selectedValue = Convert.ToInt16(((ListItem)listAccessory.SelectedItem).Value);
var foundItem = context.tblDeviceAccessories.Local.SingleOrDefault(a => a.accessory_id == selectedValue);
context.tblDeviceAccessories.Local.Remove(foundItem);
```

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

When you call the `Add` method, the objects are added to the `Local` collection with the `Added` state.

Therefore, you can delete them as follows:

```
foreach (var entity in database.tblDeviceAccessories.Local)
{
    var entry = context.Entry(entity);

    if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
        entry.State = EntityState.Detached;                    
}
```

After that, you can safely call the `SaveChanges` method.

Comment: Thank you dear, i need to delete the specific added object. have any idea?

Comment: For Example if user add battery and sim then how can delete battery or anything by specific id ?
`.Local` is what I wanted but how can access to added objects in local and can delete each?

Comment: `.Local` is what I wanted but how can access to added objects in local and can delete each?

Answer (score -2):

All Changes Before Save Change Saved To Memory
you Can work with Data before Save Change!
But you need Singlton Pattern To Create 1 Instance of DbContext And Use In the Form
But When Closed or Clicked on save Button Call Save Changes On Db Context then All changes Saved in Database